# Abort a long async function managing UX on Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vue-router

I am developing a system on which the user interacts with the webcam, doing things, talking, etc. It's mostly based around the canvas, getting the webcam image and drawing things on top.

I've implemented it as a long async function, something like:

```
async function main() {
  await showInstructions()
  await waitForPlayerStartGame()
  await showPlayerScene()
  await moveBall()
  await waitForPlayerToMove()
}
```

It's working good, but now I've ported it inside a Vue.js application, so the user can navigate across multiple pages like the one described above.

The problem is that once the big async function main is started, it won't stop. So even if the user navigates away from the page, the function will still be executing. That leads to multiple main functions executing at the same time, for example overlapping showInstructions() of the current game, but still with moveBall() executing from the previous one.

(Note that because of VUEJS router system, the navigation between pages doesn't refresh the webpage on the browser, which would fix the issue)

In this scenario, I need a way to detect when the user moves away from the current page (that's easy, I already have it). And stop the main() function execution.

One way would of course to set a globalHalt variable, and change main so that:

```
async function main() {
  await showInstructions()
  if (globalHalt) return;
  await waitForPlayerStartGame()
  if (globalHalt) return;
```

And so on. But that's not really pretty, and also it should be the same on every statement inside the submethods, each sub-sub-method, and so on and so on. Which is not pretty at all.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or is this an error by design impossible to fix? 
I was thinking, if it was Java I could do some reflection to intercept each statement, but not sure if something like that is possible on javascript.

Thanks,
Marcelo

Comment: This may be an overkill, but if you're willing to change the paradigm, then RxJS handles exactly this kind of problems splendidly.

Comment: Another alternative - if you can replace `async`/`await` with promises, you could override the `.then` callback to check for the flag automatically. Also, perhaps it is possible to extract most of the code to a webworker. They can be killed - no questions asked.

Comment: thanks for the comments! I will research RxJS and webworkers